# meta-stackoverflow downvotes should not exist

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, voting, down-votes

Who is there to judge if a suggestion is good/bad unless it had been tried before and showed good/bad results?

As far as I can see, downvotes in meta-stackoverflow only encourages people to give **suggestions that people would like to hear**

You think some ideas are plain dumb? The earth wasn't flat after all.

Comment: I thought meta down votes meant that I agree/I don't agree rather than good/bad. I could be wrong, I'm new on meta.

Comment: Uhh, people can have opinions about things. For example, my opinion is that this is a **terrible** idea. You don't have to try everything to see whether it's a good idea or not. My god, your life is either really awful or really exciting. -1 anyway.

Comment: By the way, suggestions that people would like to hear are the ones that we want to hear. Can't imagine why we'd want to do things that we don't want... Is it Friday already? Or are you trolling?

Comment: @CodyGray It's Friday!

Comment: Yes, I think some ideas are dumb. For example, I could suggest that Stack Overflow changes to use a white foreground on a white background. Are you really saying it's impossible to say that that's a stupid idea before rolling it out?

Comment: @Cody Gray nop i'd thought this is a good idea, plus I'm testing to see if my reputation will fall below 0 after a certain amt of downvotes

Comment: @Jon Skeet did someone actually suggest that? I'd actually assume we implicitly put in some common sense too

Comment: What's common sense to you isn't necessarily common sense to someone else.

Comment: @Pacerier: It's a straw man showing that your first sentence quite often has a reasonable answer of "lots of people".

Comment: @Jon Skeet i only mean what i wrote. nothing else

Comment: @pacerier: Nope, you can't go below 1. Everyone has some intrinsic value, they don't deserve negative rep, blah blah blah.

Comment: @ChrisF and that's common sense. at least to me

Comment: Who is to judge?  ***WE ARE.***

Answer (score 25):

> Who is there to judge if a suggestion is good/bad unless it had been tried before and showed good/bad results?

Plenty of people. As per my comment, if I suggested that Stack Overflow changed to use white text on a white background, I think it's entirely reasonable that almost everyone can judge that to be a bad suggestion without actually trying it.

> You think some ideas are plain dumb?

Yes, I do.

Comment: change the verb **judge** to **declare** perhaps its more explicit. pardon me for using words with multiple nuances

Comment: @Pacerier: That doesn't change my answer. I think it's pretty reasonable for people to declare that they believe a suggestion is good or bad.

Comment: @Pacerier: I can't think of any word that means what I *think* you mean that I would end up agreeing with.

Comment: @Jon Skeet you do know what i mean. I've stated it in the previous post.

Comment: @Pacerier: You missed "that I would end up agreeing with".

Comment: @Jon Skeet alright, then there's no word to describe it then.

Answer (score 14):

## meta-stackoverflow upvotes should not exist

All the good ideas have already been suggested. The only new ideas on meta are terrible. And should a good idea come along, the SE team will implement it regardless of votes.

Upvotes just **give people false hope that their dumb ideas have merit**.

You think some ideas aren't dumb?

Comment: @Jon's Evil Twin show me a link to that question then. the main idea of my message is that every suggestion has some value **as long as they are not written by a troll**. if your common sense tells you that white text on white background does not come from a troll, then there's nothing much i could do right?

Comment: if you think my message is too personal then i would suggest you read that message again without these 7 words: **You think some ideas are plain dumb?**

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable counter-proposal. +1 for clever execution.

Comment: @Jon's Evil Twin show me a link to that question **meta-stackoverflow upvotes should not exist** asked by a user who meant that as a suggestion

Comment: @Pac - I honestly have no idea what you're asking me to link to. But I think your browser may have satire disabled.

Comment: @Jon's Evil Twin if your's had satire enabled, you would have known why I'm asking you for that link