# Down votes should not have any side effect, on meta

Tags: feature-request, support, questions, meta, post-ban

After my [first suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90091/meta-stackoverflow-downvotes-should-not-exist), I've now got a new suggestion: down votes should not have any side effect in meta.

By side effects, I mean something like banning me from asking questions due to too many down votes, which I am experiencing right now:

[image: Blocked!]

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this/86998#86998) states that I am permanently banned unless I improve my standing by posting some quality answers.

Seriously, I'm new to the site, and thus I'm not capable of posting quality answers on Meta.

So my only refuge was to create a new account. I think this check for previously downvoted posts should be disabled on Meta.

Comment: I have deleted the comment discussion and reopened -- please check if my edit comes close to what you were trying to say.

Comment: @balpha actually my original post is a question at the same time. Specifically I'm asking "so what other solutions may i have other than creating a new account"

Comment: You have answered that yourself. Post helpful answers. It's not really hard to get upvotes on meta.

Comment: i mean i don't get it why the downvote?

Comment: Actually you had around -3 a while ago and it seems a few people up-voted. In meta, most of the questions and answers are highly subjective, so it is common for someone to downvote just because it does not like your proposal, nothing personal, and no explanation is really needed.

Comment: @yms dang that's just irresponsible. downvotes need a reason man

Comment: My point is, you should not take downvotes on meta so serious... you may get downvotes just because of that.

Comment: By the way, I was one of the up-voters, since I do share your opinion on this, but I saw your "first suggestion", and even when I am fairly new in meta it really looked to me like a cry for downvotes... sorry :)

Comment: @yms Because downvotes make me unable to post any more questions. I don't mind them as long as they do not give me trouble. Right now  I've got to create a new meta account just to contribute suggestions to the site? Then those suggestions will get downvoted just because people don't like them? Then I'll have to make my 3rd account because i can no longer post any more questions?

Comment: @yms and you tell me not to take it so seriously.. did you know i have still not been able to post any new questions / post any new suggestions in Meta for over a month?

Comment: Related: [Should the automated ban on questions used on SO apply to Meta as well?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question banning should work differently on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I agree - the filter should definitely be removed on Meta. The system was built to filter low-quality questions identified by downvotes. On Meta, Downvotes signify disagreement and not *necessarily* low quality, so users shouldn't be blocked just because they have downvoted contributions.

It's always been my impression that normal moderation has always been enough to deal with problematic content on Meta.

Comment: The filter already is relaxed on Meta (currently, anyway, but I doubt that will be changed, for the very reasons you give).

Comment: @Pekka's other trolling account .In case you miss the posts that were deleted, meta is not limited to just SO. its a place for all stackexchange sites. source: http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @Pacerier I think Pekka knows that well.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Based on his previous replies (they were deleted you see) its clear that he doesn't (or perhaps he don't mean what he typed?)

Comment: @Pacerier I did not say that Meta is "limited to SO". I said that things pointed out in the Meta FAQ *apply* to SO

Comment: @balpha its not *relaxed* on Meta. If you are like me unable  to post any new questions / post any new suggestions in Meta for over a month you will agree with me.

Comment: I agree with this 100% - I once got a warning from meta just because I received downvotes due to disagreement.  Nothing wrong on my part.  Put yourselves in the end user's shoes, no point in doing it this way...