# Give users the option to disable the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, stack-exchange-button

We need a way to disable the Stack Exchange bar at the top-left of every SE site.

I'm not saying *take it away*. I'm saying give us the *option* to take it away.

It's noise IMHO. It shows me replies across all the SE sites. If I wanted to see a response, I'd hit the response tab on my [user page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159916/pacerier?tab=responses).

After I visit the response tab, the number icon in the SE bar (top left) doesn't decrease, so I have to take one more step (clicking that bar); otherwise, later, I will think I have replies though I've already read them.

I can understand why people generally aren't having this issue. I'm having this issue because I use 11 different [SE sites](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632951/pacerier?tab=accounts). If you actually use that many different SE sites, you can understand my situation.

Say if there are 10 new answers in your SuperDrowndown and you've only got time to read 3 of them right now? You'd hit that superdropdown read 3 of them and there is no indication that 7 of them are still unread. See my point now? I'm missing out my replies because I don't often have time to "clear all the replies" in 1 shot

Comment: @Pacerier Because we disagree.

Comment: This sounds like a job for... [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/)!

Comment: @muntoo but do you know if you downvote me too vigorously the system will ban me from posting any more new questions/suggestions?

Comment: @Pacerier This is the only place I've downvoted you (nothing personal, just being a good citizen). I'm sure the 8(+?) other people have a similar opinion to me. And, yes, I was aware of that.

Comment: <s>Hmmm... It looks as if you've only [2 accounts](http://stackexchange.com/users/8f7761b7-8326-4a88-8e0e-4a9a0922c803?tab=accounts): SO, and MSO. Perhaps you should associate the other ones? This way, everything will be "all-in-one", and you won't have this "problem". (I hope.)</s> [Uhhh...](http://stackexchange.com/users/025e323f-864d-4cb8-8c50-8cf7390a8012?tab=accounts)

Comment: Downvotes are different here on Meta than they are on the main site. As muntoo says, they indicate **disagreement**, particularly for a question tagged `feature-request`, rather than meaning "this is a bad question that shouldn't have ever been asked in the first place". It's unlikely you'll be banned from posting future questions on Meta just because this one has been severely downvoted.

Comment: @muntoo: [I see 11 accounts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159916/pacerier?tab=accounts). Pacerier [had to reregister with a new account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/down-votes-should-not-have-any-side-effect-on-meta).

Comment: @Cody: [He _has been_ banned from posting future questions on Meta.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/down-votes-should-not-have-any-side-effect-on-meta)

Comment: @Hendrik: Interesting. My suspicion is that figuring out ways to get around the account ban is a *really* good way to get that ban reinstated with prejudice...

Comment: @muntoo this is the correct link http://stackoverflow.com/users/632951/pacerier?tab=accounts

Comment: @Cody Gray you apparently didn't know the reason why I was banned so what's with that judgement

Comment: It wasn't about you in particular. You're right, I had no idea that you were even banned, and I never did and still don't know the reason. It's not really my business. My point, however, is still valid. Figuring out ways to get around the account ban is a really good way of getting that ban quickly reinstated.

Comment: @Cody Gray . you apparently didn't know the reason why someone (anyone, not just me) will be banned from asking questions at all do you?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, I'm aware of the reason. I don't need to be educated; I've answered many questions about it myself. The trick is that you have to be a *repeat* offender. Asking one bad question isn't enough to trigger the automatic block. That's good because we all acknowledge that edge cases exist and people make mistakes. You only get "banned" from asking questions if you repeatedly ask bad questions that add nothing of value to the community. The standards are pretty rigorous, but intentionally not fully disclosed. I have a fair understanding of them, but they haven't been applicable to me.

Comment: @Pacerier, concerning your recent edit: My solution is to open each of the responses in a new tab; then I can take my time and work through those tabs.

Comment: BTW, the solution to the 'not enough time to read them all' is to ask for a [tag:feature-request] saying *detect whether I 'read' (click) the 'message'; if I do, 'unhighlight' it*.

Answer (score 8):

From the TOS:

> StackExchange™ MultiCollider
>   SuperDropdown™ is property of
>   StackExchange™. Suggestions of its
>   removal will not be tolerated, and
>   will result in your immediate termination.

---

FYI, I have 25+ accounts on SE sites, and I don't really "*understand my [your] situation*". (I probably only use 15+ of them, though.)

---

Try [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/) or [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom), and set a custom filter, if it annoys you so much.

Comment: perhaps you don't have that much activity as me even though you had several more accounts compared to mine?

Comment: @Pacerier I find the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ very useful; it allows me to quickly check up on responses/etc with a "single" click. I'd rather not go to each SE site and go to the response page.

Comment: so what if there are 10 new answers in your SuperDrowndown and you've only got time to read 3 of them right now? You'd hit that superdropdown read 3 of them and there is no indication that 7 of them are still unread. You get it? i'm missing out my replies because I don't often have time to "clear all the replies" in 1 shot

Comment: @Pacerier I use my infallible memory to memorize the ones I've been to or not. A better feature-request, instead of disabling the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, would be to detect links you've clicked on (to answer/reply to/etc).

Comment: gd point but i don't think you should downvote this thread at all even if its not an upvote its fine.

Comment: Why is a suggestion of its removal not tolerated and why does it result in a immediate termination? That's a bit harsh...

Comment: @bizso09 You will understand the more you use StackExchange... And the more you get to know me. >:D

Answer (score 3):

Oh no please! Do not take this away from me! And do not allow others to hide the notification regarding a message I sent! 
However it is true I would like the "responses" tab in the profile to be updated when I already read the comment or answer by using the bar. But that is a different issue.

Comment: I'm not saying take it away of course. I'm saying giving us the Option to take it away or put it as it is. btw i've edited the question

Comment: The problem I see with this is that the only "invasive" notifications we have left are precisely these ones, since email notification has been denied repetedly. If an option for disabling this is offered then it is very likely that many users will not be resposive enough about comments and answers. Even if it is just "optional".

Comment: On the other hand, the issue with syncronization between the notification bar and the responses tab is indeed a bit unconfortable, maybe you sould create a new feature-request, bug-report or discussion about that specific point. Please do not blame me if you get downvoted again... meta is kind of unpredictable :)

Answer (score 3):

Apply whiteout to your eyeglasses? Seriously, why not just ignore it?

Comment: i can. but this is just a suggestion you see. isn't meta for suggestions?

Comment: To get the team interested you will have to offer some better reason than 'I want it ...' something about it that is actively problematic.

Comment: because i think applying whiteout to  eyeglasses is not what an average person will do?

Comment: No, that's true. Most people would apply the whiteout to their *monitors*, rather than their eyeglasses. How silly of this answer!