# Is there any procedure to return a good name to an account?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, ban

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do when getting "Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this)

I was banned (SO) for asking an unpopular question. (I think they were following the Stack Overflow rules, but I will be more cautious now.)
Is there any procedure to return a good name to my account?
Can I do anything helpful for Stack Overflow, or just ask some committee to investigate my case?

My only purpose is to uncover problem spots; I'm surely not a help vampire, as I am not afraid of working, and I've tried to provide some self-aswered questions that turned out unpopular too. (Now people will be looking for these answers, but I'm not risking to publish such Q/A.)

Comment: Basically, contributing some good answers that receive upvotes from fellow community members is a possible way to reinstate your account's ability to ask questions. Try to do that first, and if the ban isn't automatically lifted, then you'll need to come back here and ask for someone to re-consider your unique situation.

Comment: I truly hope you did not get the question-ban for asking a single off-topic question. Did you delete things that now are no longer visible in [your public profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/264727/outmind)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "banned"?

Comment: I received question-ban for asking an "off-topic" question "What is the ideology of C programming language?". Then people said me that I should be more concrete. I've concretized my question by asking about core concepts of C - which is pretty concrete things (and I got answers), as "ideology" could be very ambiguous in different contexts. Then I received my question-ban for this "duplicate" question, which was not duplicate, but concretization.

Comment: I've read about Help vampires while following the instruction `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.`

Comment: Like Arjan said, you really should not have been banned from asking questions just for asking one or two off-topic questions. That ban is intended for *repeat offenders*, people who perpetually ask bad questions and don't make any effort to heed the rules set out in the FAQ or mend their ways. If you haven't already deleted several *other* off-topic or poor-quality questions (causing them not to show up in your profile), then something **is** definitely wrong here.

Comment: And the ridiculousness continues... that is, if we're not missing some of the truth of the situation here; either way, if this is a 'strange case', isn't it rather restrictive and muting that the question is closed - seeing as no one can clear up the details / or go about thinking how it might have been unjustified in this instance? The duplicate is just a generic manual which will basically tell the OP to put up with it until _they_ can correct it, but if _they're_ not particularly in the wrong? ...

Comment: @Cody Gray Dear Cody Gray, could you please check my account, as it seems that you are an administrator. I remember the problem with one self-answered question related to Eclipse, but it was very long ago and I have stopped ask such questions (do I think it is right or not).

Comment: @Mr. D., I'm very biased seeing that outmind is not responding to our comments about *other* deleted things. Without details on that, for me, the benefit of the doubt for the automatic ban filter and for the team not spending time on this, rather than for outmind. I've seen many [other example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86594/getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this-account-after-20-months-and-900-reputation)s of banned users who in the end had a lot of cruft deleted. (But, true, the user of that one example improved a lot!)

Comment: @Arjan: Indeed, I'm curious as to what we're not being let in on; but I don't like to be _tooooo_ presumptuous when deceit isn't clearly being employed. And, I suppose closing does prevent duplicate answers that don't reach the incident with the right specificity.

Comment: I am not an administrator. You will need a moderator (look for the diamond) to check your account; they are the only ones who can see all of your deleted questions. But you should be able to tell us if you've deleted any, or you've asked any that don't appear in your profile...

Comment: I have deleted questions: "What is the ideology of C programming language?" as it was "vague". I have deleted self-answered question about Eclipse, as it was downvoted. That's all I can remember.

Comment: By the way, who is Mr. Defend?

Comment: @Cody I'm trying to deduce my deleted questions from my profile, but `Reputation on deleted posts and votes is not shown here.`. I see `Peer Pressure` badge at `2010-06-07 22:47:52Z`, but I think that it is related to "self-answered" question I've mentioned above.

Comment: @Cody Gray How can I find the `diamond` moderator? I've checked MOS and SO users for diamond and found no one who looks like a moderator.

Comment: Well, [Bill the Lizard](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) is one, but it doesn't really matter which one. Use the flag link on this question (below the tags), select the "other" option, and ask them to check your deleted questions and explain why you've been automatically banned. I suspect that what they'll do is re-open this question and post an answer.

Comment: If this is caused by two downvoted questions, then related: [Down votes should not have any side effect, on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/down-votes-should-not-have-any-side-effect-on-meta).

Comment: It's about SO, not an MSO account.

Comment: in general you should email the address at the bottom of every page, but I have disassociated that question from your account per your request.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff! Thank you, Cody!