# Warn users who are about to hit the "we are no longer accepting..." wall

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

I'm no longer able to post questions on Meta. I get the "We are no longer accepting questions from this account" message. I have a large number of downvoted questions here. Well, actually, there were only two such questions, but I'm not arguing. It is a fair deal. Like in aviation, rules on stack exist for a reason.

I'm asking to be warned about such things.
I've seen dozens of different informational banners and popups on Stack Exchange sites.
They provide help, inform you about/explain something.

But I haven't seen a warning like I describe. It would be nice to have one. Or not?

Comment: Are you sure you've been banned for only *two* downvotes? That looks pretty far-fetched to me, maybe it happened for another reason entirely.

Comment: Actually, since downvoting questions on meta means something completely different than on other sites, I would suggest that it shouldn't figure as strongly in question ban algorithm.

Comment: I'm not sure in anything, because I'm a newbie to here. I have only 5 questions on meta, and 2 of them with really high amount of downvotes. As far as I've considered meta a place for discussions, in some sense not always 100% constructive.

Comment: Looks like the low quality question detector is already relaxed for meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks it is odd that a user that says he's banned from asking questions on meta asks a question on meta about it?

Comment: Related: [Down votes should not have any side effect, on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91377/down-votes-should-not-have-any-side-effect-on-meta).

Answer (score 10):

**If you aren't able to post questions on meta, what exactly am I answering here?**

Seriously, though, I  think this is a good idea.  The drawback I can see is that it may make it easier for users to game the system.

If you warn someone when they are about to cross that threshold it makes it more likely that the system can and will be abused.

Comment: Well, I've answered a couple of times, and several times tried to post question. But each time I so "we are no longer accepting" message. Than I've tried once again, and it was ok (my rating grows a little, I guess). Lack of clarity is also a reason I'm strongly requesting for being ban more informative.

Comment: It's pretty clear what the reason is in most cases.  Often it's related to a lot of deleted questions, too.  Do you have any deleted questions on meta?

Comment: No, I haven't as far as I remember.