# A site that is a "Where should I ask this question?" site

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I am speaking both for myself and others as well.  I would greatly appreciate and utilize a site that one could ask where to ask a certain question.  I have seen questions like that on this site, but instead of asking a question here, which is for the improvement of the site, why not create a dedicated site just for where to ask questions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: I can't imagine how one would uphold any kind of quality standards on such a site.  It doesn't sound like a good fit for the SE model.

Comment: I am not ***entirely*** sure what you are asking here....

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Sort of... but this is more of "I have a question that applies to both electrical engineering and software development, so where should I ask it?"

Comment: This sounds a little too meta.

Comment: @jadarnel27 I totally understand what you mean, without the framework of a dedicated topic, a site can get unruly...

Comment: @Rocket, What does that mean?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral exactly.

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA But, if I have a question that could fit into two categories, where should I find out where to ask it?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral come to the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) and ask our opinion ^_^ (you need 20 meta rep 1st tho...)

Comment: So if this site got created, where would you ask questions if you could ask a question on that site?  Its meta would be like itself or something O.o

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I already asked the question I was referencing... but I will in the future!

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Oh yeah...  Well once I get 200 rep in one site, I can transfer 100 over to the others... Right?  (because I am at 122 in Gaming)

Comment: @CodeAdmiral haha no. You don't transfer anything ^_^. You might get the +100 bonus :-P

Comment: @Rocket Good point...  Well, I can't say I have a good answer for that...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Sorry, wrong word choice :(  Anyways, the bonus still counts for meta sites, right?

Comment: Pointless. If the question *seems* like it'd be on topic for a particular site after reading their FAQ, post it there. Let it be migrated if the site's users disagree. No big deal. If you're still not sure after reading the FAQ, post a question to the per-site Meta. Whatever you do, don't spam all the sites with your question, or all the per-site metas with your meta-question.

Comment: Stop downvoting... You're killing him!

Comment: @Kal: No, downvotes won't kill you on Meta anymore. [Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123068/153008). Feel free to downvote something if you feel that it's a bad idea, as per the [FAQ].

Comment: @CodyGray sounds good to me.  I will do that.

Comment: @Kalamane Thank you, don't have much to lose though...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Personally, I don't really think this works with the Stack Exchange model.  The topic of this site would be

> "Is this question on-topic for Stack Exchange sites?  If so, which one
>   does it fit best in?"

It seems to me that the only experts on that topic would be regular users of the various sites, or possibly people that have read (in detail) the various per-site metas and FAQs.

These questions would probably be a good fit for the per-site metas, actually.  From your comment:

> "...I have a question that applies to both electrical engineering and
>   software development, so where should I ask it?"

It seems that you could post your proposed question to the Electical Engineering meta, and say "*Is this question a good fit for the site?*".  Those would be the most qualified people to answer that.

If you cannot narrow your domain down to one or two potential SE sites (and thus ask on their meta), then perhaps you need to put some more thought into your question =)

Comment: Really good point... I haven't looked at it that way.  But, I am not saying that this is for people new to StackExchange, its kind of like the difference between CodeReview and StackOverflow, as I didn't know how the two were different before I did a little digging

Comment: Plus what would a site's meta be if the site itself was "where do I ask this?"  Would its meta just be itself?

Comment: @Rocket That could be a possiblity.  Well, does the StackExchange "main" site have a meta?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral: [It used to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange).  It's now this one (meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @Rocket Really?  I haven't been using this network of Q&A sites for that long.

Comment: So, in the end, go to the two sites' metas that I could ask the question on, and ask if it is a good fit, right?

Comment: @CodeAdmiral I think that the "digging" is by design.  People *should* have to do some reading and researching before posting.  That helps weed out low quality and off-topic questions.

Comment: @CodeAdmiral That is what I would do.  You may find that the answer is already on that per-site meta.  There's usually a tag for that (like [scope] or something similar).  Sometimes the ground will already have been covered.

Comment: @jadarnel27 Alright, that makes sense.  (for both comments)