# Don't ban users for asking bad questions, but mark their questions instead

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, post-ban

You said that this Stack Exchange web sites are question and answer sites, not help forums.

[What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers#answer-86998)

Yes that is true, BUT isn't the point people to be helped. Just btw this kind of questions might not help other but usually they will get similar errors and Google will point back to those stupid non-usable questions.

The point of the Stack Exchange network is people to be helped. So my proposal is that when a question "non-valuable", just add it some kind of badge "NON Valuable". Don't ban the user who asked.

Usually when you ask a question for something you don't understand you can't really make the question valuable for others.

Also there isn't a place where you can get help like Stack Overflow. It's the best way to ask a programming question and not to be answered a year after that.

So what is your opinion about this?

Comment: *"Also there isn't a place where you can get help like Stack Overflow."* Any thoughts on why this might be?

Comment: The user ban is one of the most essential features of this site. Without it, overall question quality would plummet catastrophically. Collect some experience with community moderation (flag queue, closevoting, etc.) for a while before making such a suggestion. This is one feature that must never, never be taken away. Ever. There's enough crap as it is.

Comment: See also ["Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).

Answer (score 23):

> when a question "non-valuable", just add it some kind of badge "NON Valuable". Don't ban the user who asked.

We're not banning users for asking one or two bad questions. They get banned for doing so *repeatedly*, without improving themselves.

So, no, thanks. I think the automatic ban works just fine.

Comment: Could be, @MrLister. It could even be an issue with a shared IP address. But there's always the "If you really, *really* think the ban is an error" part in that same FAQ. Here on Meta, so far *all* my time spent on folks who were banned "for no reason" eventually appeared to have more bad content (like deleted by the author or the community) than they were telling us... But of course, the possibility of true errors are the reason to keep investigating/responding to people who feel they were banned erroneously.

Comment: And also, @MrLister, given that I originally started that FAQ, for a long time I saw *all* the comments that banned users posted to that question until it was locked. Really, most commenters had no clue, looking at the contents of those comments...

Comment: So, is this ban still in effect then, @MrLister? Then I assume it's on Meta? I already upvoted [Question banning should work differently on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta). Maybe you can comment there, though meanwhile that is marked status completed.

Answer (score 16):

Bad questions are already marked as "non valuable" in two ways:

1. They are down-voted.
2. They are closed.

Anyone can ask a bad question, however, if you **persistently** ask bad questions then the system saves the rest of us the trouble.

Comment: Upvoted because I prefer "persistently" to "repeatedly".

Comment: Not that I care about the upvote, @BoltClock (I upvoted this too), but really just curious (not being a native English speaker): does "persistently" feel so much different from "repeatedly, without improving themselves"?

Comment: @Arjan: Well, they're about the same I guess. "persistently" just has a nicer ring to it.

Comment: @Arjan: persistently connotes that you do so "with purpose".

Answer (score 6):

You do bring up a good point.  I wouldn't mind if questions that figured heavily into a question ban were automatically flagged for moderator attention by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) *in addition to* the question ban being applied.  These are definitely **not** posts we want to show up in Google, so most of the time they should just be deleted.

Comment: I have a feeling this isn't _exactly_ what the OP had in mind, but interesting idea nonetheless.