# Why is the account of a spammer not deleted immediately?

Tags: discussion, spam, spam-detection

User [Jing Liu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/193714/jing-liu) is posting spam. I flagged his four posts as *spam* and all posts were removed. But this user has been a member for the last six days (from his profile). Why are such users not removed immediately? Is there another process for this?

Before I posted this question, the account of that spammer was removed. But my question is:
Is there any rule that if a user makes more than some number of spam posts then the account of the user is deleted?

Comment: He's gone now...

Comment: Yes. I show after posting the question. But my question is: **Is there any condition that if a user post some number of spam then only the account of the user is deleted?**

Comment: I don't know, but I did see some mention of merging accounts and monitoring spammers to gain behavioural and machine-learning data.

Comment: After so many deletions, they'd become question-banned and wouldn't be able to post their spam anymore.

Comment: Are you asking about automatically due to number of posts flagged as spam?

Comment: @random I am asking if it is automatically or manually? And how many time can a user post spam?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depends on who is looking at the account and posts on if they nuke the booty.

Could be the community blasted the spam with flags, meaning a moderator didn't come across it. And that process could have repeated a few times. There are windows where moderators (those who put sticks of dynamite in the teeth of spammer jammers) just don't see a post because of the top flight community sic.

But when it does skirt across the table of a moderator things do not end well for that account.

This spammer was scorched a few minutes before your post came up.

As to the question ban, [unfortunately the rate was lowered some on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta?lq=1) because of the way people perceive a difference in downvotes. So the automatic kick up the chin takes a little more to activate its Dennis Rodman powers.