# User Blocking should be much different on Meta SO

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161363/13295) just brought up something I didn't realize, that somebody could be blocked on Meta.  He had one [heavily downvoted post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/154755/13295), but since downvoting works differently on Meta, I don't think he should be blocked for asking a standard newbie question.

Is there an algorithmic difference to block on Meta as opposed to SO?  Should there be?

Comment: One downvoted post surely didn't post-ban a user on meta... maybe there are some deleted ones as well?

Comment: According to the [meta-tag:status-completed] tag on [Question banning should work differently on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109263/question-banning-should-work-differently-on-meta), there is already a difference.

Comment: In addition to that one, he had three more heavily downvoted and deleted questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156723/vote-correct-answer-by-users , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155791/offensive-and-humorous-questions , http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155690/notification-to-user-for-getting-answers so it wasn't just the one that triggered this. Two were at -3 when deleted, and one at -18.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson, it seems like we'd want people to delete their own crappy questions and encourage it, but that's a different issue than what I brought up.

Comment: Note, the link I just voted-to-close as duplicate is the correct one, since it is a 'discussion' question as opposed to a feature-request.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - Yeah, self-deletion as a ban metric is troublesome. On the one hand, we want to prevent people from jerking others around by rapidly posting and deleting bad questions (which does happen), but on the other it does cause a few well-meaning users to inadvertently ban themselves.

Answer (score 4):

Automatic post blocking on Meta is already different.

The algorithm has been adjusted for the different voting patterns here.

Comment: Well, apparently not very well, since this user has only made legitimate support questions (yes, with more english skills needed).

Comment: @LanceRoberts: How do you know that he has? How many questions have been deleted? There are several users here on Meta with more than just one heavily-downvoted question that have not been banned.

Comment: I'm not a mod, no way to know.  (Though I've always thought self-deleting questions was a stupid criteria for a ban).

Comment: @LanceRoberts I think self-deletion counts a lot less on active accounts than on newer accounts.  It had to be included in the ban algorithm because some help vampires were asking questions, deleting them if they weren't answered in a few hours, and reposting the exact same question.